# indexes don't affect time execution in ms sql 2014 VS mysql (mariaDB 10)

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2014, database-performance, database-indexes

I'm porting statistics analyzer system from MySQL (MariaDB 10) to MS SQL 2014, and I found a strange thing. Normally I used to use single- and multi-field indexes for most operations: statistics database holds about 60 millions of events on 4-core pc, and analysis includes funnels, event segmentation, cohort analysis, KPIs and more, so it may be slow sometimes.

But I was quite surprised when I've executed several query sequences from on MS SQL and then removed all indexes (except the main clastered id):  I saw that execution time even decreased! I've restarted server (cache is cleared) but after each restart result was similar - my queries work faster without indexes (actually speed is the same, but no time is spent on manual indexes creation ).

I suppose MS SQL creates implicit indexes for me, but in this case it looks like I should remove all indexes creation from my queries? In MySQL you can clearly see that adding indexes really works. Does this MS SQL behaviour mean that I don't need to care about indexes anymore? I've made several tests with my queries and it seems that indexes almost don't affect execution time. Last time I dealed with MS SQL was a long ago and it was MS SQL 2000, so maybe MSFT developed f**n' AI during last 15 years? :)

---

Just in case this test sql code (generated by back-end for front-end) is below.
In short it produces graph data for particular type of events for last 3 months over time, then does segmentation by one parameter. It creates temp table from main events table with user set constraints (time period, parameters), creates several more temp tables and indexes, does several joins and returns final select result:

```
select  min(tmstamp), max(tmstamp)
    from  evt_db.dbo.events
    where  ( ( source = 3 )
              and  ( event_id=24 )
              and  tmstamp > 1451606400
              AND  tmstamp < 1458000000 
           ); 
select  min(param1), max(param1), count(DISTINCT(param1))
    from  evt_db.dbo.events
    WHERE  ( ( source = 3 )
              AND  ( event_id=24 )
              AND  tmstamp > 1451606400
              AND  tmstamp < 1458000000
           ); 

create  table #_tmp_times_calc_analyzer_0_0 (
    tm_start int, 
    tm_end int, 
    tm_origin int, 
    tm_num int
);

insert into  #_tmp_times_calc_analyzer_0_0 values
( 1451606400, 1452211200, 1451606400, 0 ), 
( 1452211200, 1452816000, 1452211200, 1 ), 
( 1452816000, 1453420800, 1452816000, 2 ), 
( 1453420800, 1454025600, 1453420800, 3 ), 
( 1454025600, 1454630400, 1454025600, 4 ), 
( 1454630400, 1455235200, 1454630400, 5 ), 
( 1455235200, 1455840000, 1455235200, 6 ), 
( 1455840000, 1456444800, 1455840000, 7 ), 
( 1456444800, 1457049600, 1456444800, 8 ), 
( 1457049600, 1457654400, 1457049600, 9 ), 
( 1457654400, 1458259200, 1457654400, 10 );
```

And...

```
CREATE INDEX tm_num ON _tmp_times_calc_analyzer_0_0 (tm_num); 

SELECT  id, t1.uid, tmstamp, floor((tmstamp - 1451606400) / 604800) period_num,
        param1 into #_tmp_events_view_analyzer_0_0
    FROM  evt_db.dbo.events t1
    WHERE  ( ( source = 3 )
              AND  ( event_id=24 )
              AND  tmstamp > 1451606400
              AND  tmstamp < 1458000000
           ); 

CREATE INDEX uid ON _tmp_events_view_analyzer_0_0 (uid);

CREATE INDEX period_num ON _tmp_events_view_analyzer_0_0 (period_num);

CREATE INDEX tmstamp ON _tmp_events_view_analyzer_0_0 (tmstamp);

CREATE INDEX _index_param1 ON _tmp_events_view_analyzer_0_0 (param1);

create table #_tmp_median_analyzer_0_0 (ts int );

insert into #_tmp_median_analyzer_0_0
    select  distinct(param1) v
        from  #_tmp_events_view_analyzer_0_0
        where  param1 is not null
        order by  v ; 

select  tm_origin, count(distinct uid), count(distinct id)
    from  #_tmp_times_calc_analyzer_0_0
    left join  #_tmp_events_view_analyzer_0_0 ON period_num = tm_num
    GROUP BY  tm_origin; 
select  top 600 (param1) seg1, count(distinct uid), count(distinct id)
    from  #_tmp_events_view_analyzer_0_0
    GROUP BY  param1
    order by  1 asc;
```

And...

```
select  seg1, tm_origin, count(distinct uid), count(distinct id)
    from  
      ( SELECT  (param1) seg1, tm_origin, uid, id
            from  #_tmp_times_calc_analyzer_0_0
            left join  #_tmp_events_view_analyzer_0_0 ON period_num = tm_num
            group by  param1, tm_origin, uid, id 
      ) t
    GROUP BY  seg1, tm_origin; 
select  min(param1), max(param1), round(avg(param1),0)
    from  #_tmp_events_view_analyzer_0_0; 

DECLARE @c BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #_tmp_median_analyzer_0_0);

SELECT  round(AVG(1.0 * ts),0)
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  ts
            FROM  #_tmp_median_analyzer_0_0
            ORDER BY  ts OFFSET (@c - 1) / 2 ROWS
                FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - @c % 2) ROWS ONLY 
      ) AS median_val;
```

Comment: you'd have to use a query profiler to figure it out, but in some cases, it is cheaper to do a full table scan than it is to scan an index. you may have found one of those cases.

Comment: all queries that generates the system are tested and profiled on mysql, indexes were created to speedup particular queries, and they really helped - on mysql. does this mean that logic of compound indexes on different db engines are not the same?

Comment: and the second case - generating "star" scheme for OLAP: inner join by > 10 tables, main has 60M rows. in mysql I need indexes for this to work, in mssql again one clastered in main is enough. mssql analyser asks for index, but created it does not speedup anything.

Comment: If you can show the execution plans for the queries, one with the indexes and one without, then it would be easier to see what is going on.  SQL server doesn't create "implicit" indexes, the closest you get to that is a clustered primary key or unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

`evt_db.dbo.events` needs `INDEX(source, event, tmstamp)`, with `tmstamp` 3rd.  In the case of MySQL, those first 2 `SELECTs` will run entirely in the index (because it is a "covering" index).  `source` and `event` can be in either order.

Later, you have a similar `SELECT` but it also has `id, t1.uid`.  You could make this covering index for it:  `INDEX(source, event, tmstamp, uid, id)`.  Again, `tmstamp` must be third in the list.

`select  top 600 (param1) seg1, count(distinct uid), count(distinct id) ...` might benefit from `INDEX(param1, uid, id)`, where `param1` must be first.

The other indexes you list are possibly not useful at all.  What indexes did you try?

One difference between MySQL and other Databases -- MySQL almost never uses more than one index in a query.  And, in my experience, MySQL's choice is 'wise'.  Perhaps MSSql is trying too hard to use two indexes, when simply scanning the table would be less work.

Comment: this code is generated programmatically and only needed parameters are extracted to the result table. as user may want to analyze any event parameter (event has about 15 parameters) I can't create an index for each of them  (and also several compound) in main events table. 'source' and 'event_id' in this case will not be in result dataset. only time, uid, id and param1.

Comment: ok, I will not remove index creation and test with indexes and without. Btw, first benchmarks show that MSSQL on the similar dataset (data type mapping involved) works without generating indexes 3-4 times faster than MySQL. And this is MariaDB 10, which somewhat faster original engine.

Comment: In MySQL 10x faster is often seen, depending on whether the data/index is cached or not.  So, to have a 'fair' comparison, be sure to tune the cache sizes appropriately, plus either deliberately work with a cold cache, or run the query twice to be sure the cache is primed.  (Apologies if I am telling you something you already know.)

Comment: everything is right, done many times, and yet 3x-4x faster on my tasks.